# Generating Script from MDF database

Tags: c#, database, mdf

I have a mdf database file that I am using in my project with ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

It is possible in Server Explorer to get a script file of the database by pressing:

Data Connections => Tabels => [My table Name]Images =>Show Table Data => Script to file

This will get a script that will insert data into the database.
What I what to achieve is a script (That I can add to git) that will create the database and insert all data.

**Question** (Just to be clear): How do I in code generate the script that built my database and inserts data?
**Example**:

```
GetTheScriptFromMDFDataBase() =>

“CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageFileName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Image] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id], [ImageFileName]) VALUES (6337, N'L:\Database of fundus images\Not fundus images\epicam not fundus\2017-03-02_10-42-40_video_000000405.jpeg')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id], [ImageFileName]) VALUES (6338, N'L:\Database of fundus images\Not fundus images\epicam not fundus\2017-03-02_10-42-40_video_000000406.jpeg')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id], [ImageFileName]) VALUES (6339, N'L:\Database of fundus images\Not fundus images\epicam not fundus\2017-03-02_10-42-40_video_000000407.jpeg')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id], [ImageFileName]) VALUES (6340, N'L:\Database of fundus images\Not fundus images\epicam not fundus\2017-03-02_10-42-40_video_000000408.jpeg')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Image] ([Id], [ImageFileName]) VALUES (6341, N'L:\Database of fundus images\Not fundus images\epicam not fundus\2017-03-02_10-42-40_video_000000409.jpeg')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Image] OFF
```

I have been looking at 
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) 
 But not being able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the script into your code as under:

1. Save the entire script as a text file e.g. DbScript.txt
2. Add 'DbScript.txt' as embedded resource. Click Project Menu > YourProject Properties > Resources > Add Resource > Add Existing File (then browse and select DbScript.txt file).
3. In your code write

   ```
   string s = YourProject.Properties.Resources.DbScript;
   ```

Comment: I do not want to add the script to my code. I want to generate the script from code